# Best UI library for Python passing parameters from textboxes in UI to backend and result from backend to divs in front end

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface

I have tried different libraries to create an interface for a program I built with Python yet always found difficult sharing the data.

I want to pass variables from the UI to call methods in the backend and in return return results in divs of the UI.

Comment: Is this a web site or Python standalone application?

Comment: If it's a web app use ajax

Comment: a webpage with python